How to apply method of perturbation to system of PDEs?
I have a hard time to apply the method of perturbation to a system of coupled PDEs which arises in a physical problem (therefore certainly has a unique solution). It is question of a 2D problem in the region of a quarter of an annulus, where the unknowns are $\vec F $ and $g$ are vector and scalar fields respectively.
$g$ has Dirichlet boundary conditions at $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi /2$. And vanishing Neumann b.c.s on the 2 remaining curves.
$\vec F$ has vanishing Neumann b.c.s on all sides, which means $F_r=0$ at the inner and outer radii and $F_\theta=0$ at $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi /2$.
The PDEs are $a \nabla \cdot \nabla g +b |\vec F|^2-g(d\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x}+e \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial y}    )=0$, $\nabla \times F=\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial y \partial x}\hat z$ and $\nabla \cdot F =0$. Where $a$, $b$, $d$ and $e$ are constants.
I have approached the problem by considering the simplified equation $\nabla \cdot \nabla g =0$, whose solution is a linear in $\theta$ $g$. The problem is that after a semi ton of algebra steps, applying separation of variables, I get a $\vec F$ that cannot satisfy the boundary conditions at $r=r_{inner}$ and at $r=r_{outer}$. Which I think means that the physical fact that $\vec F$ is constrained inside the region is due to the other (or perturbation) terms in the above PDE. Therefore, I do not know which simplified equation to consider in order to apply the method of perturbation. Any idea is welcome.
Note: $x$ and $y$ are the usual Cartesian coordinates and $r$ and $\theta$ are the usual polar coordinates.

How can the curl of $F$ be equal to a scalar $g_{x y}$?

@MatthewCassell by forgetting to add a $\hat z$ ;)
